# Get specific data from API response using parameter

Tags: python, json, bybit

I'm unsure how to word the title of this question and no doubt there is an easy solution but I am a beginner.

I need to pass a parameter (symbol) to this function and have it return the 'minTradeQuantity'.

```
def get_exchange_minqtyize(symbol):
    return session_auth.query_symbol()['result']
```

I can retrieve the whole result response with the function like this, but if I add `['result'][0]['minTradeQuantity']` I can retrieve the 'minTradeQuantity' of the first name in the JSON response. How can I filter using the symbol parameter as 'name' to obtain the value I require?

The whole JSON response from the API docs is below:

```
{
"ret_code": 0,
"ret_msg": "",
"ext_code": null,
"ext_info": null,
"result": [
    {
        "name": "BTCUSDT",
        "alias": "BTCUSDT",
        "baseCurrency": "BTC",
        "quoteCurrency": "USDT",
        "basePrecision": "0.000001",
        "quotePrecision": "0.01",
        "minTradeQuantity": "0.0001",
        "minTradeAmount": "10",
        "minPricePrecision": "0.01",
        "maxTradeQuantity": "2",
        "maxTradeAmount": "200",
        "category": 1,
        "innovation": false,
        "showStatus": true
    },
    {
        "name": "ETHUSDT",
        "alias": "ETHUSDT",
        "baseCurrency": "ETH",
        "quoteCurrency": "USDT",
        "basePrecision": "0.0001",
        "quotePrecision": "0.01",
        "minTradeQuantity": "0.0001",
        "minTradeAmount": "10",
        "minPricePrecision": "0.01",
        "maxTradeQuantity": "2",
        "maxTradeAmount": "200",
        "category": 1,
        "innovation": false,
        "showStatus": true
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the result & filter by `symbol`:

```
def get_exchange_minqtyize(symbol):
    data = session_auth.query_symbol()['result']
    for sym_data in data:
        if sym_data['name'] == symbol:   # assuming the name here is the symbol you're looking for
            return sym_data['minTradeQuantity']
```